# How to auto-generate and assign variables corresponding to elements in a matrix?

Tags: c++, python, matlab, optimization, matrix

I am working on a binary linear program problem.

I am not really familiar with any computer language(just learned Java and C++ for a few months), but I may have to use computer anyway since the problem is quite complicated.

The first step is to declare variables m_ij for every entry in (at least 8 X 8) a matrix M.
Then I assign corresponding values of each element of a matrix to each of these variables.

The next is to generate other sets of variables, x_ij1, x_ij2, x_ij3, x_ij4, and x_ij5, whenever the value of m_ij is not 0.
The value of x_ijk variable is either 0 or 1, and I do not have to assign values for x_ijk variables.

Probably the simplest way to do it is to declare and assign a value to each variable, e.g.

```
int* m_11 = 5, int* m_12 = 2, int* m_13 = 0, ... int* m_1n = 1

int* m_21 = 3, int* m_12 = 1, int* m_13 = 2, ... int* m_2n = 3
```

and then pick variables, the value of which is not 0, and declare x_ij1 ~ x_ij5 accordingly.

But this might be too much work, especially since I am going to consider many different matrices for this problem.

Is there any way to do this automatically?

I know a little bit of Java and C++, and I am considering using lp_solve package in C++(to solve binary integer linear program problem), but I am willing to use any other language or program if I could do this easily.

I am sure there must be some way to do this(probably using loops, I guess?), and this is a very simple task, but I just don't know about it because I do not have much programming language.

One of my cohort wrote a program for generating a random matrix satisfying some condition we need, so if I could use that matrix as my input, it might be ideal, but just any way to do this would be okay as of now.

Say, if there is a way to do it with MS excel, like putting matrix entries to the cells in an excel file, and import it to C++ and automatically generate variables and assign values to them, then this would simplify the task by a great deal!

Comment: As far as I understood you want to generate `x_ijk, k=1..5` for each `m_ij != 0`. How do you define values for these `x_ijk`?

Comment: miy) x_ijk values do not have to be defined. it's either 0 or 1, and the values are solution to the set of inequalities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab indeed seems very suitable for the task. Though the example offered by @Dr_Sam will indeed create the matrices on the fly, I would recommend you to initialize them before you assign the values. This way your code still ends up with the right variable if something with the same name already existed in the workspace and also your variable will always have the expected size.

Assuming you want to define a square 8x8  matrix:

```
m = zeros(8)
```

Now in general, if you want to initialize a three dimensional matrixh of size `imax`,`jmax`,`kmax`:

```
imax = 8;
jmax = 8;
kmax = 5;
x = zeros(imax,jmax,kmax);
```

Now assigning to or reading from these matrices is very easy, note that length and with of m have been chosen the same as the first dimensions of `x`:

```
m(3,4) = 4; %Assign a value
myvalue = m(3,4) %read the value
m(:,1) = 1:8 *Assign the values 1 through 8 to the first column

x(2,4,5) = 12; %Assign a single value to the three dimensional matrix
x(:,:,2) = m+1; Assign the entire matrix plus one to one of the planes in x.
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you could use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of vectors, like

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
```

You don't need to use separate variables for the matrix values, why would you when you have the matrix?

I don't understand the reason you need to get all values where you evaluate `true` or `false`. Instead just put directly into a `std::vector` the coordinates where your condition evaluates to `true`:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int> true_values;
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].size(); j++)
    {
        if (some_condition_for_this_matrix_value(matrix[i][j], i, j) == true)
            true_values.emplace_back(std::make_pair(i, j));
    }
}
```

Now you have a vector of all matrix coordinates where your condition is `true`.

---

If you really want to have both `true` and `false` values, you could use a [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) with a [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) containing the matrix coordinates as key and `bool` as value:

```
// Create a type alias, as this type will be used multiple times
typedef std::map<std::pair<int, int>, bool> bool_map_type;
bool_map_type bool_map;
```

Insert into this map all values from the matrix, with the coordinates of the matrix as the key, and the map value as `true` or `false` depending on whatever condition you have.

To get a list of all entries from the `bool_map` you can remove any `false` entries with [`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
std::remove_if(bool_map.begin(), bool_map.end(),
    [](const bool_map_type::value_type& value) {
        return value.second == false;
    };
```

Now you have a map containing only entries with their value as `true`. Iterate over this map to get the coordinates to the matrix

---

Of course, I may totally have misunderstood your problem, in which case you of course are free to disregard this answer. :)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The reason I need separate variables is that I need to use those variables to build a set of constraints(equations and inequations). can I do this with std::vector? I'm sorry if this is a silly question.

Answer (score 0):

I know both C++ and Matlab (not Python) and in your case, I would really go for Matlab because it's way easier to use when you start programming (but don't forget to come back to C++ when you will find the limitations to Matlab).

In Matlab, you can define matrices very easily: just type the name of the matrix and the index you want to set:

```
m(1,1) = 1
m(2,2) = 1
```

gives you a 2x2 identity matrix (indices start with 1 in Matlab and entries are 0 by default). You can also define 3d matrices the same way:

```
x(1,2,3) = 2
```

For the import from Excel, it is possible if you save your excel file in CSV format, you can use the function `dlmread` to read it in Matlab. You could also try later to implement your algorithm directly in Matlab.

Finally, if you want to solve your binary integer programm, there is already a built-in function in Matlab, called `bintprog` which can solve it for you.

Hope it helps!